# bash: intensive rw operations cause to damaged files

Tags: bash, awk

I have big txt files (for example, let it be 1 000 000 strings each) and I want to sort them by some field and write data to different output files in several dirs (one input file - one out dir). I can do it simply with awk:

```
awk '{print $0 >> "dir_"'$i'"/"$1".some_suffix"}' some_file;
```

if I process files one-by-one it always works well, but if I try to work with many files at the same time, i usually (not always) receive some output files truncated (I know exactly count of fields, it's always the same in my case, so it's easy to find bad files). I use command like

```
for i in <input_files>; do    
awk '{print $0 >> "dir_"'$i'"/"$1".some_suffix"}' < $i &
done
```

so each process creates files in own out dir. Also I tried to parallelize it with xargs and received the same results - some random files were truncated.

How could this happen? Is it RAM, or filesystem cache problem, any suggestions?

Hardware: RAM is not ECC, processors AMD Opteron 6378. I used ssd (plextor m5s) and tmpfs with ext4 and reiserfs (output files are small)

Comment: Are you positive that each of your files is being written to a separate directory? Is there any chance that `$1` contains `/`?

Comment: Also, most importantly, do you wait until the loop is done, or do you run it again while it hasn't finished its job yet?

Comment: hi, $1 doesn't contain / . Yes, I wait until all child processes are completed and wipe files before run script again

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running out file descriptors in your `awk` process, if you check carefully you'll find that maybe the first 1021 (just under a power of 2, check `ulimit -n` for the limit) unique filenames work. Using `print ... >>` does not have the same behaviour as in a shell: it leaves the file open.

I assume you are using something more contemporary than a vintage `awk`, e.g. for GNUs `gawk`:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html

> Similarly, when a file or pipe is opened for output, awk remembers the file name or command associated with it, and subsequent writes to the same file or command are appended to the previous writes. The file or pipe stays open until awk exits.
>
> This implies that special steps are necessary in order to read the same file again from the beginning, or to rerun a shell command (rather than reading more output from the same command). The close() function makes these things possible:
>
> ```
> close(filename)
> ```

Try it with `close()`:

```
gawk '{
    outfile="dir_"'$i'"/"$1".some_suffix"
    print $0 >> outfile
    close(outfile)
}' some_file;
```

`gawk` offers the special `ERRNO` variable which can be used to catch certain errors, sadly it's not set during output redirection errors, so this condition cannot be easily detected. However, under `gawk` this condition *is* detected internally (error `EMFILE` during an open operation) and it attempts to close a not recently used file descriptor so that it can continue, but this isn't guaranteed to work in every situation.

With `gawk`, you can use `--lint` for various run-time checks, including hitting the file-descriptor limit and failure to explicitly close files:

```
$ seq 1 1050 | gawk --lint '{outfile="output/" $1 ".out"; print $0 >> outfile;}'
gawk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1022) warning: reached system limit for open files: 
    starting to multiplex file descriptors
gawk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1050) warning: no explicit close of file `output/1050.out' provided
gawk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1050) warning: no explicit close of file `output/1049.out' provided
[...]
gawk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1050) warning: no explicit close of file `output/1.out' provided
```

Comment: Thanx, I thought only `system()` calls have limit... it's my mistake. But yesterday and today I created about 3 000 000 files using `close()` and 3 or 4 of them were damaged. I think I have to collect more info about this trouble, anyway thank you